# Singleton in a complete metric space is a complete metric space, but has no interior point. Baire?

Tags: metric-spaces, complete-spaces, baire-category

I am confused by the above statement with the follwing version of Baire's category theorem:

> If a non-empty complete metric space $(M,d)$ is the countable union of closed sets, then one of these closed sets has non-empty interior.

A singleton in a complete metric space is a complete metric space. By Baire's theorem the singleton should have an interior point, which I believe it does not.

Comment: The singleton has empty interior in the bigger space (unless it is an isolated point), but it does not have empty interior has a topological space of its own with the subspace topology

Comment: If the single point is $x $ and the whole space is $X$, mustn't $\{x\}$ be both open and closed? If $\{x\}$ is both open and closed, it has an open nbhd of itself, so is an interior point? Maybe look up discrete spaces and their topologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it has an interior point. If $p\in M$, then $p$ is an interior point of $\{p\}$, if we see $\{p\}$ as a metric subspace of $M$. Of course, in $M$, the set $\{p\}$ has, in general, no interior point (it has only if $p$ is an isolated point of $M$).

Comment: A point $P$ of a subset $S$ of a metric space $(M,d)$ is an interior point of $S$ if there is some $r>0$ such that $D(p,r)\subset S$. In particular, if $S=M$, every point $p\in M$ is an interior point of $M$. And, in particular, $p$ is an interior point of the metric space $(\{p\},d)$.